# MySQL Jquery update array?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, arrays

i have a small website where people can submit name ideas for a project i am working on

Two things i want to implement are an upvote button (+1 to current score)
and when someone submits a name it will update the mysql array using ajax.

I am very new to Ajax and i have managed to work some code together that submits a name without leaving the current page.

This is my code for the mysql array that displays underneath the name submission form.
How can i link this upto a form submit button for refresh when a name is submitted?

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM namevotes ORDER BY upvote desc") 
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "<center>";
echo "<table border='1' id='tablea'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['upvote'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>";
echo "</center>";
?>
```

I am want to add a button next to each row that will increase the "upvote" by one, i know how to rig one up that will manually upvote a single entry, im not sure how to direct it to each array entry.

Comment: where is jquery code?

Comment: first, ajax = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. And there is nothing connected to ajax in the code you are showing. secondly, narrow down your problem, we are not going to write the code for you. If you got more code that is **relevant** for your question, then please post it.

Comment: The jquery code does not exist for this script, i have implimented it into the submission form only and im curious to how i can refresh an array using jquery, im fully aware no ones going to write my code for me and i dont expect it, im just curious if someone can point me in the right direction for refreshing the array.

Comment: This is putting me in the right direction, im sure i can work something out with it
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 0):

Method is very simple:-> 
1> add button in while clause using `<button id="{row['id']}">like me</button>`

2> create a jquery element in webpage that onclick on hitlike button trigger a event: fetch data from url by get {or post} method with data `?hitlike=id`

3> before code in php tag, put if statement that `if(isset($_GET['id']))` then `UPDATE table SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=$_GET['id']`

4> rest code will be the same to show data

//I haven't tried this but I think it should work